# Does the resources of a localhost testserver equal the resources of the computer itself?

Tags: localhost

I have a webapplication that i occasionally run on localhost. It is a spring boot application running on an embedded tomcat server. Say my computer has a cpu of 2.1 ghz and 8 GB of RAM, does this mean the application/tomcat server running on localhost also has 2.1 ghz of cpu processing power and 8 gb of ram at its disposal? Or does a localhost server always get a certain amount of both allocated and nothing more?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No... but also no.

- The operating system is not just an abstraction: it requires some resources, too.
- The web server requires some of the resources, leaving less for your application.
- There might be other applications competing of the resources.
- There can be some *limitations* configured, too. These tells the maximum resources the web server / application can consume. On the other hand, this kind of limitations on the other applications may leave more resources for your application.
- It's also possible to *reserve* some resources (like memory) for the application.